# Install PyQGIS in virtualenv

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

Is it possible to install PyQGIS in virtual environment? I want to use rendering capabilities in my own application which runs using virtualenv.

Comment: PyQGIS doesn't seem to be available via `pip`. Would it be acceptable if PyQGIS was installed globally and you had access to it within your Python virtual environment? That's pretty easy to do.